# Limit involving a diverging series

Tags: limits, divergent-series

It is a known fact that the value of the sum $\Sigma \frac{1}{i}$ (when $i$ ranges over the integers) Diverges. But what is the solution of the following limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Sigma_{i=0}^n 1/i}{n}$$

Comment: The Harmonic series is well-known to grow like $\log(n)$. The requested limit goes to zero. A more interesting question is the limit of $S_n-\log(n)$.

Answer (score 3):

It is known that

$$ \frac{\ln (n+1)}{n}<\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{i}}{n}<\frac{1+\ln n}{n}$$

Which follows from integration.

Thus $$0= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln (n+1)}{n} \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Sigma_{i=0}^n 1/i}{n} \le \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+\ln n}{n} =\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0 (\because \text{L'Hospital})$$

Answer (score 0):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\leq \sqrt{N\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}} \leq \sqrt{2N}$$
hence your limit is trivially zero.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n \to L, $ then $(a_1 + \cdots + a_n)/n \to L.$ Apply this with $a_n = 1/n,L=0.$